# Cómo usar wsprintf, char y LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Estoy tratando de hacer un método de logs, para registrar actividad.

Este es el método:

```
void PutEventLog(char *cMsg)
{ 
  FILE *pFile;
  errno_t err;
  LPCWSTR lpcwstr_Buffer;
  char cBuffer[512];
  SYSTEMTIME SysTime;
  err = fopen_s(&pFile, "Server Logs\\Gate Server Logs\\Gate Server Events.log", "at");
  if (err != 0) return;
  GetLocalTime(&SysTime);

  ZeroMemory(cBuffer, sizeof(cBuffer));
  wsprintf(lpcwstr_Buffer, (LPCWSTR)L"(%d:%d)-(%d/%d/%d) - ", SysTime.wHour, SysTime.wMinute, SysTime.wDay, SysTime.wMonth, SysTime.wYear);
  wcstombs(cBuffer, lpcwstr_Buffer, 512);

  strcat_s(cBuffer, cMsg);
  strcat_s(cBuffer, "\n");
  fwrite(cBuffer, 1, strlen(cBuffer), pFile);
  fclose(pFile);
}
```

Estos son los errores que tengo:

> ```
> LINE:
> wsprintf(lpcwstr_Buffer, (LPCWSTR)L"(%d:%d)-(%d/%d/%d) - ", SysTime.wHour, SysTime.wMinute, SysTime.wDay, SysTime.wMonth, SysTime.wYear);
> error C2664: 'int wsprintfW(LPWSTR,LPCWSTR,...)': PARAMETER 1 can not convert FROM 'LPCWSTR' TO 'LPWSTR'
>
>
> LINE:
> wcstombs(cBuffer, lpcwstr_Buffer, 512);
> error C4996: 'wcstombs': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using wcstombs_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
> _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
> ```

¿Alguien podría explicarme como reestructurar el código?

Comment: ¿Por qué el título en inglés?

Comment: Los que están votando a esta pregunta, que dudas tienen?

Answer (score 1):

> LINE: wsprintf(lpcwstr_Buffer, (LPCWSTR)L"(%d:%d)-(%d/%d/%d) - ",
> SysTime.wHour, SysTime.wMinute, SysTime.wDay, SysTime.wMonth,
> SysTime.wYear); error C2664: 'int wsprintfW(LPWSTR,LPCWSTR,...)':
> PARAMETER 1 can not convert FROM 'LPCWSTR' TO 'LPWSTR'

El error está claro, le está pasando a wsprintf en el primer parámetro (el buffer de destino) un puntero constante (o sea, de solo lectura).

LPWSTR -> puntero a cadena widestring con lectura y escritura 
LPCWSTR -> puntero a cadena widestring de solo lectura (const)

Pero incluso aunque le ponga a la variable el tipo LPWSTR, el programa no va a funcionar, porque a ese "buffer" no se le ha asignado memoria alguna, lo ideal entonces es que sea declarado de la misma forma que el otro buffer:

```
wchar_t wBuffer[512];
// (...)
wsprintf((LPWSTR)wBuffer, (LPCWSTR)L"(%d:%d)-(%d/%d/%d) - ", SysTime.wHour, SysTime.wMinute, SysTime.wDay, SysTime.wMonth, SysTime.wYear);
```

Eso debería funcionar.

**Relevante también para su pregunta** (del propio es.stackoverflow.com):
[¿qué <strike>demonios</strike> es un LPCTSTR?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/38887/91)