# Convertir string a LPCTSTR c++

Tags: c++, windows

Estoy buscando la manera sencilla o algun modo de convertir un string a LPCTSTR porque ultimamente tengo problemas con esto. Por ejemplo tengo un string cualquiera:

```
string welcome;
```

Y quiero usar este string en mi `LPCTSTR`.

```
LPCTSTR ejemplo = "aqui vendría mi string welcome compatible con LPCTSTR";
```

Pero no consigo hacerlo compatible.

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar, debemos saber ¿qué <strike>demonios</strike> es un `LPCTSTR`?.

#### `LPCTSTR`.

Es simplemente un puntero constante a `char` o `wchar_t` oculto tras una alias:

- **L**‌ong.
- **P**‌ointer.
- **C**onst.
- **T**char.
- **STR**‌ing.

La parte más confusa es el **T**char, que resulta ser otro alias con la particularidad que define uno u otro tipo de `char` dependiendo de si la macro `UNICODE` está o no está definida: en caso de estar definida el tipo `TCHAR` será un alias de `WCHAR`<sup>1</sup> y si no será un alias de `char`.

En cuanto a la parte de *puntero largo* (**L**ong **P**ointer) es una distinción entre punteros de 16 bits (short pointer) y punteros de 32 bits (long pointer), si no me equivoco los *punteros cortos* están en desuso y son un remanente de las plataformas de Windows de 16 bits.

Así que tu código:

```
LPCTSTR ejemplo = "aqui vendría mi string welcome compatible con LPCTSTR";
```

Sería equivalente a:

```
const char *ejemplo = "aqui vendría mi string welcome compatible con LPCTSTR";
```

O bien, con `UNICODE` definida:

```
const wchar_t *ejemplo = "aqui vendría mi string welcome compatible con LPCTSTR";
```

#### Problema.

**Se te ha olvidado publicar el error de compilación** que tienes, así que voy a intentar adivinar cuál es.

Lo que estás haciendo es:

```
string welcome;
const char *ejemplo = welcome;
```

O bien, con `UNICODE` definida:

```
string welcome;
const wchar_t *ejemplo = welcome;
```

Estás confundiendo el objeto [`string`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) con un literal de cadena de texto (`const char *` o `const wchar_t *`) que son tipos distintos y al compilador no le gusta:

> ```
> error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' in initialization
> error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const wchar_t*' in initialization
> ```

El objeto `string` es una clase que almacena en un búfer interno una cadena de texto, maneja el ciclo de vida de dicho búfer y ofrece funcionalidades adicionales para el manejo y gestión del mismo. Un puntero a caracter (`char` o `wchar_t`) es un tipo básico.

#### Solución.

Si quires acceder a los datos internos de un objeto `string` debes usar el método [`string::data`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) o [`string::c_str`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str); estos métodos devuelven un puntero al inicio del búfer que contiene la cadena<sup>2</sup>.

```
string welcome;
LPCTSTR ejemplo = welcome.c_str(); // equivalente a const char *ejemplo
```

O bien, con `UNICODE` definida:

```
wstring welcome;
LPCTSTR ejemplo = welcome.c_str(); // equivalente a const wchar_t *ejemplo
```

Fíjate que en el caso de estar en modo `UNICODE` el `string` debe ser de caracteres anchos (wide string: `wstring`).

#### Consejos.

1. **NO USES LOS ALIAS DE MICROSOFT**, no son portables (es decir: no existen en otras plataformas así que tu código sólo compilaría para Windows), son confusos (esconden el tipo real tras un alias), son obsoletos (distinguen entre punteros largos y cortos) <strike>y son feos</strike>.

Usa las cosas tal y como son con las herramientas que ofrece el propio lenguaje C++:

```
string welcome;
const char *normal = welcome.c_str();

wstring wwelcome;
const wchar_t *unicode = wwelcome.c_str();
```

2. **No accedas a los datos internos de un `string`**, no se qué uso le quieres dar al `LPCTSTR ejemplo` pero apuntar a los datos internos de un objeto es muy propenso a errores (por ejemplo: si se destruye `welcome` el puntero `ejemplo` seguirá apuntando al mismo lugar pese a que la memoria haya sido borrada) usa el objeto `string` directamente.

---

<sup>1</sup>Que a su vez será un alias de `wchar_t` o `unsigned short` dependiendo de si la plataforma para la que se compila tiene soporte nativo a caracteres anchos o no.

<sup>2</sup>El estándar establece que `string::c_str` debe devolver un puntero a una cadena de caracteres acabada en caracter nulo mientras que `string::data` no tenía esta garantía hasta después de C++11.